# How can I resolve this python and django settings import idiosyncrasy?

Tags: python, django, import, settings

I have a file layout like this:
`settings/`
`----__init__.py`
`----common.py`
`----configs/`
`--------constants1.py`
`--------constants2.py`
`----debug/`
`--------include1&2.py`
`--------include1.py`
`--------include2.py`

and when I import `settings.debug.include1`, I would like the settings file to execute/import `common.py` then override the settings in `common.py` with the proper constants file. Problem is, this isn't happening. Is there a way to accomplish my goals in this fashion?

Comment: By "specify `settings.debug.include_.py`", do you mean `import settings.debug.include1`?

Comment: Oh, and in the code using the settings, you want to say `from settings import *` and always retrieve the proper set of settings?

Comment: Well, you could put the logic that decides which set of settings to load into common.py and import the appropriate debug/configs module from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Use `from ... import *` or `execfile()` in `settings/__init__.py` to load the appropriate files.

Answer (score 0):

As most comments are already hinting at you can use `from module import *` in the appropriate files. They might look like the following..

--

```
# settings/common.py

DEBUG = False
```

--

```
# settings/configs/constants1.py

CONSTANT_1 = 'One'
```

--

```
# settings/configs/constants2.py

CONSTANT_2 = 'Two'
```

--

```
# settings/debug/include1.py

from settings.common import *
from settings.configs.constants1 import *

# Override settings here
DEBUG = True
CONSTANT_1 = '1'
```

--

```
# settings/debug/include2.py

from settings.common import *
from settings.configs.constants2 import *

# Override settings here
DEBUG = True
CONSTANT_2 = '2'
```

And for the combination of the 2 debug includes

```
# settings/debug/include1and2.py

from settings.debug.include1 import *
from settings.debug.include2 import *
```

OR

```
# settings/debug/include1and2.py

from settings.common import *
from settings.configs.constants1 import *
from settings.configs.constants2 import *

# Override settings here
```